# How to make NSSpellChecker work with NSDocument?

Tags: macos, cocoa, spell-checking

I have a core data / document-driven macOS app, using Swift and I struggle on combining the out-of-the-box spell checking API with an `NSDocument` (`NSPersistentDocument` in my case)

It took me more time than it should take, but this is what I got, mostly guided by this great [answer](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/7134-using-cocoa-spelling-panel-in-carbon-application.html):

```
 class VTDocument: NSPersistentDocument, NSChangeSpelling {
    [...]  
    private let spellchecker =  SpellChecker()

@IBAction func showGuessPanel(_ sender: Any?){
        spellchecker.startSpellCheck(nodes: Array(db.nodes), tag: 0)
    }

@IBAction @objc func changeSpelling(_ sender: Any?){
    spellchecker.replace(with: "Test")
}
```

This is leading me to see the NSSpellChecker.spellingPanel, correctly showing the word to correct. However, the changeSpelling function should be "called" by the panel but is never called. The above spellChecker is a simple wrapper around the NSSpellChecker that keeps the status between function calls.

The SpellChecker class looks like this.

```
import Cocoa


class SpellChecker {
    let checker = NSSpellChecker.shared
    let count: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    var nodes = Array<Node> ()
    var nodeNr = 0
    var stringPos = 0
    var range: NSRange = NSRange()

    func startSpellCheck(nodes: [Node], tag: Int ) {
        self.nodes = nodes
        nodeNr = 0
        stringPos = 0
        continueChecking()
    }

    func continueChecking(){
        if nodes.count == 0 {
            return
        }
        if nodeNr >= nodes.count {
            checker.updateSpellingPanel(withMisspelledWord: "")
            checker.spellingPanel.orderFront(self)
            return
        }
        if let nodeText = nodes[nodeNr].label {
            range = checker.checkSpelling(of: nodeText, startingAt: stringPos, language: nil, wrap: false, inSpellDocumentWithTag: 0, wordCount: count)
            if count.pointee > 0 {
                stringPos = range.lowerBound
                checker.updateSpellingPanel(withMisspelledWord: nodeText[range])
                checker.spellingPanel.orderFront(self)
                return
            }
        }
        nodeNr = nodeNr + 1
        continueChecking()
    }

    func replace(with: String){
        if let nodeText = nodes[nodeNr].label {
            let text = nodeText as NSString
            text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: with)
            nodes[nodeNr].label = text as String
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the document in the responder chain? Does another object in the responder chain catch `changeSpelling` before the document?

Comment: Thanks @Willeke. To be frank, it's not my area of expertise. The showGuessPanel is called as part of the responder chain, catching the message coming from the menu. I was expecting that it would remain in the responder chain. And you are right. As it looks the responder chain stops right there, with the spellingPanel. Made the SpellingChecker an NSResponder and assigned. Still not working, but I believe I am a big step forward. Thank you!

Comment: In the meanwhile, I added the NSChangeSpelling protocol to a few classes, including NSApplication and AppDelegate. I am not getting any changeSpelling(_:) call. Could there be a bug? Is nobody using the spellingPanel anymore?

Comment: I'll have a try. Which class is the first responder?

Comment: Thanks again for asking the right question. The NSDocument was part of the responder chain, but it isn't anymore. Indeed, the showGuessPanel  is reaching the NSDocument through the responder chain, but the changeSpelling doesn't. As I said, it's not my area of expertise, but I don't understand why this changed. But thanks to your question did I find out how to find the firstResponder and could traverse the responder chain. Now found the NSView that displays the NSDocument is in the responder chain. Not wrong, but why did the chain change? Thanks!

Comment: Is the document associated with the frontmost window? Is the focused control a text field or text view?

Comment: Thanks for helping me understanding this @Willeke. Much appreciated. I think I can confirm that it is the frontmost window. However, thinking about it, the spellingPanel got an orderFront(), so technically, it's not. In any case, the document is representing a graph, whose nodes contain text. I do highlight the node in the view when showing the error. So, yes changes happen, but I still struggle with the idea that the document is sometimes in the responder chain and sometimes not. I moved the function over to the document related view and all is fine as the view is in both cases part of chain.